Upon PC restart, MySQL service on local computer "started and then stopped"
I'm working in MySQL on a local (Windows) computer. I have a somewhat recurring issue I have with managing the server. I cannot replicate this error because I do not know what causes it.
Sometimes, I'll be doing a data manipulation in the server. And then, I'll shut down the PC after I am done. Upon PC restart, I get the infamous "the MySQL service on local computer started and stopped" error when trying to start the service via services.msc (or the command line). This error occurs even without editing the my.ini file or any other under-the-hood components of MySQL. It occurs even when there is no mysqld or mysql-esque tasks in the Task Manager. Most times, I just have to wait an indeterminate amount of time for this error to go away so that I can restart the service successfully. But it is quite annoying.
Virtually all of the advice toward a workaround involves re-initializing the server, which would wipe the database. That is NOT an option.
Are there any resources out there to successfully start the service when this error shows up randomly? I think I've noticed that when I force-stop a query in Workbench that involves large tables, this error can occur more frequently.
To anyone who comes across this problem in the future: MySQL apparently continues to complete a process even after you force-stop a query (e.g. in Workbench). If you shut off your PC before this process completes, you'll get the "started and then stopped" error when trying to start the MySQL service in services.msc. Do not re-initialize your server; just wait few hours, days, etc. for the process to complete. Then you'll be able to restart the service (you'll just have to keep trying to "Start" the service on services.msc until successful)

You need to study the Windows event log and the MySQL error log to find the reason.

Thanks @nbk . Just for clarification, you're saying i should keep the computer on for the forseeable future and pray it work through its issues on its own? Yes, I interrupted several queries that worked with big data (although I kept MySQL on and was running other queries successfully) prior to shutdown; could my forced interruptions be the problem?

Thanks @nbk. You were right and the problem is now fixed (if you make a suggested answer, I will approve it)--to anyone who comes across this problem in the future: MySQL apparently continues to complete a process even after you force-stop a query (e.g. in Workbench). If you shut off your PC before this process completes, you'll get the "started and then stopped" error. Do not re-initialize your server; just wait few hours, days, etc. for the process to complete. Then you'll be able to restart the service (you'll just have to keep trying to "Start" the service on services.msc until successful)
